# Не могу добавить кастомный класс кнопке на яндекс-картах под ИЕ11

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, internet-explorer, ie11

Я создаю кнопку на карте с помощью следующего кода:

```
const clusterShowButton = new ymaps.control.Button({ data: {
    content: SVG_CLUSTER_SHOW,
    title: 'Отключить кластеризацию',
    selectOnClick: true,
    size: 'small'
  }
});
```

Далее я пытаюсь добавить ей кастомный класс:

```
clusterShowButton._layout._buttonElement.className += 'my-button';
```

Во всех остальных браузерах этот метод работает, кроме Internet Explorer 11, потому что там `clusterShowButton._layout === null`.

Вопросы:

1. Как навесить кастомный класс? (предложенный мною метод больше похож
   на костыль)
2. Если следовать моему методу, как сделать так, чтобы работало в IE11?
3. Не баг ли это Yandex Maps?

Answer (score 1):

Не завязывайтесь на недокументированные внутренние сущности! Нет никаких гарантий, что ваш код будет работать в другой версии апи, т.к. разметка и стили стандартного макета кнопки не являются документированными и/или стабильными.  Так же как и все поля, которых нет в документации, особенно те, которые начинаются с подчеркивания (`_layout`/`_buttonElement`). Это не надуманная проблема, например, два года назад дизайн макеты кнопок [поменялись](https://yandex.ru/blog/mapsapi/api-yandeks-kart-versiya-2-1-48).

Вам надо создать свой макет для кнопки реализовав интерфейс [`ISelectableControlLayout`](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/ISelectableControlLayout-docpage/) как в [примере](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/button_layout).